# Operation now in progress error on connect( function) error

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I want to set timeout value of function connect but I get this error: "Operation now in progress"

My code:

```
if ((he = gethostbyname(authdefhost)) == NULL) {
        snprintf(errbuf, CERRBUFSIZ - 1, "cannot resolve %s: %s\n", authdefhost, hstrerror(h_errno));
        return -1;
}

sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
memcpy(&sin.sin_addr, he->h_addr_list[0], sizeof(struct in_addr));       

if ((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        snprintf(errbuf, CERRBUFSIZ - 1, "cannot create client socket: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
}

if ((fcntl(sd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK) < 0))
    printf("error on setting socket flags.");

if (connect(sd, (void *) & sin, sizeof(sin)) == -1) {
        snprintf(errbuf, CERRBUFSIZ - 1, "cannot connect to server %s: %s\n", authdefhost, strerror(errno));
        close(sd);
        return -1;
}

FD_ZERO(&fdset);
FD_SET(sd, &fdset);
int rv;
if ((rv = select(sd + 1, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &tv)) == -1) {
    printf("error occurred on select function.");
    return -1;
}
else if (rv == 0) {
    printf("time out occurred.");
    return -1;
}
else {
    printf("connection established");
    return sd;
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When you call `connect()` on a non-blocking socket, you'll get `EINPROGRESS` instead of blocking waiting for the connection handshake to complete. Then, you have to `select()` for writability, and check the socket error to see if the connection has completed.

From Linux's [`connect()` manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html):

> ```
> EINPROGRESS
>
>     The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be completed
>     immediately.  It is possible to select(2) or poll(2) for completion by
>     selecting the socket for writing.  After select(2) indicates
>     writability, use getsockopt(2) to read the SO_ERROR option at level
>     SOL_SOCKET to determine whether connect() completed successfully
>     (SO_ERROR is zero) or unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual
>     error codes listed here, explaining the reason for the failure).
> ```

Comment: In short: This is expected.  You need to specifically check for `errno != EINPROGRESS` in your error-checking path for `connect()`.

Comment: *Chapter 16 Nonblocking I/O* of **UNIX Network Programming (Volume 1)** describe this feature in detail and present a demo.