# Setting winsock select timeout accurately

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, winsock

I am trying to make my accept call timeout after a specified time period and I tried following the suggestion here:

[Winsock accept timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683358/winsock-accept-timeout)

in which case I pass a TIMEVAL struct to select when I call it, problem is when I set tv.tv_usec to say around 40 minutes or so, the select call times out immediately instead of waiting for the 40 minutes I specified. MSDN states that the timeout for select is the maximum time that it will wait, how do I make it such that select or accept for that matter waits for a specific time period before timing out?

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <Windows.h>

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

#include <cstdio>
#include <tchar.h>

VOID _tmain( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    WSADATA wsaData = { 0 };
    ADDRINFOA hINTs = { 0 };
    PADDRINFOA pResult = NULL;
    SOCKET hServerSocket = INVALID_SOCKET,
           hClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    TIMEVAL tv = { 0 };
    INT iReturnStatus = -1;
    DWORD dwRecvTimeout = 30000, // Milliseconds
          dwSendTimeout = 30000; // Milliseconds
    fd_set readFDs = { 0 };

    if ( WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &wsaData ) )
    {
        _tprintf_s( TEXT( "WSAStartup Failed\n" ) );
        return;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &hINTs, sizeof( hINTs ) );
    hINTs.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hINTs.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hINTs.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hINTs.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
    if ( getaddrinfo( NULL, TEXT( "9001" ), &hINTs, &pResult ) )
    {
        WSACleanup();
        _tprintf_s( TEXT( "getaddrinfo Failed\n" ) );
        return;
    }

    if ( ( hServerSocket = socket( pResult -> ai_family, pResult -> ai_socktype, pResult -> ai_protocol ) ) == INVALID_SOCKET )
    {
        freeaddrinfo( pResult );
        WSACleanup();
        _tprintf_s( TEXT( "socket Failed\n" ) );
        return;
    }

    int iResult = bind( hServerSocket, ( pResult -> ai_addr ), pResult -> ai_addrlen );
    if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        freeaddrinfo( pResult );
        closesocket( hServerSocket );
        WSACleanup();
        _tprintf_s( TEXT( "bind Failed\n" ) );
        return;
    }
    freeaddrinfo( pResult );

    if ( listen( hServerSocket, SOMAXCONN ) )
    {
        closesocket( hServerSocket );
        WSACleanup();
        _tprintf_s( TEXT( "listen Failed\n" ) );
        return;
    }

    hClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    for ( ;; )
    {
        tv.tv_usec = 2400000000; // microseconds
        FD_ZERO( &readFDs );
        FD_SET( hServerSocket, &readFDs );
        _tprintf( "select()\n" );
        iReturnStatus = select( 0, &readFDs, NULL, NULL, &tv );

        // Select Error
        if ( iReturnStatus == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {
            _tprintf( "select Failed\n" );
        }
        // Select Success
        else if ( iReturnStatus )
        {
            // Connection Established On Server Socket
            if ( FD_ISSET( hServerSocket, &readFDs ) )
            {
                // Accept Client Connection
                hClientSocket = accept( hServerSocket, NULL, NULL );
                if ( hClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
                {
                    _tprintf( "accept Failed\n" );
                }
                else
                {
                    // Set Recv Timeout
                    setsockopt( hClientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, ( const char * ) &dwRecvTimeout, sizeof( dwRecvTimeout ) );

                    // Set Send Timeout                 
                    setsockopt( hClientSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, ( const char * ) &dwSendTimeout, sizeof( dwSendTimeout ) );

                    // Process Client Request(s)
                    // HandleConnection( ClientSocket );
                }
            }
            // Connection Established On Unknown Socket
            else
            {
                _tprintf( "Invalid Socket Returned\n" );
            }
        }
        // Select Timeout
        else
        {
            _tprintf( "select Timeout\n" );
        }

    }
    if ( hServerSocket != INVALID_SOCKET )
        closesocket( hServerSocket );

    return;
}
```

Comment: MSDN says max time because the `select` wait ends if the socket will not block on accept.  So either your select call isn't correct or a connection is available on the listening socket.  If you post some code, it might be possible help you.

Comment: Checkout, is the timeout specifies in seconds or minutes. I think it must be in seconds not in minutes.

Comment: `tv.tv_usec` is microseconds, and `tv.tv_sec` is seconds. Also, please show the code you use for initializing the structures/fd_sets and the `select` call.

Comment: added code, units used should be correct

Comment: Just a thought, why not set `tv.tv_sec` to `2` and `tv.tv_usec` to `400000`? It's just the same as you have now, but more "correct". :)

Comment: Also, I know this is a Windows-only program, but you should make it a good habit to set the first argument to `select` correct just in case you in the future have to do it on a platform where the argument is used, so you don't forget it then.

Comment: tv.tv_sec = 2400;  
tv.tv_usec = 0; //2400000000; microseconds
ok if i do it like this, it won't timeout immediately but why is this so?

Comment: Because you use tv_sec for timeouts *GREATER* than 1 second, tv_usec for timeouts *LESS* than 1 second, and you should *NOT* allow tv_usec > 1,000,000.

Comment: `tv.tv_sec = ( timeout_in_microseconds / 1000000 ); tv.tv_usec = ( timeout_in_microseconds % 1000000 );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why is this so?

This is per defintion.

Verbatim from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> tv_sec
>     Time interval, in seconds.
>
> tv_usec
>     Time interval, in microseconds. This value is used in combination with
>     the tv_sec member to represent time interval **values that are not a
>     multiple of seconds**.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with tv.tv_usec; tv_usec as per man page is of type 'long'. The value (2400000000) **is out of range of long** and that is the reason you are getting such select system behavior.

If you want select to wait for 40 min then make sure you are using tv.tv_sec.

Comment: the range of long is -2147483648 and 2147483647.

Comment: I wonder if tv_usec=2147483647 really would lead to a time out of 2147s, but 0.483647s ... - no win32 available right now to check.