# c++ client with response on different port

Tags: c++, sockets

I am writing client in c++ (socket programming) but the server has two options to send to client request and also server can send data on specific port(lets say port ZZ). I want the client listening on port ZZ non-blocking.
How can I do it? Would select() command will help me? or is there any other technique to implement this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the non blocking mode or you use a very small block time (like one millisecond).

To active non blocking mode you have to configure your socket alike.

See [Beejs Guide to socket Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) to learn how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. How can I put small block time?

Comment: see for example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181784/how-to-set-socket-timeout-in-c-when-making-multiple-connections (linux), on windows you need to check out the winapi socket functions (winsock)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use multithread is a better choice.
You can use recive reponse tin the main thread and listen the port ZZ in another thread.

Comment: yeah I am doing same but when I create thread to listen on port ZZ. it just stuck in the while loop.

Comment: What kind of protocol do you use? TCP or UDP? If you use tcp, you must establish a connection first.