# TCP Dead link detection

Tags: c, linux, tcp, network-programming, posix

How can i detect a dead link in a TCP Connection?
Dead Link occurs when someone pulls the network cable,
Shut down the Network Interface, turns of WiFi or,
as in my case... unplugs the power supply.

**Keep-alive only works for the client but not for the server.**

The Server is just receiving data, never sending so using TCP_USER_TIMEOUT
will not work cause the send q will always be empty.

I don't want to implement an Application Layer protocol cause of the speed loss.
(no zero copy anymore)

One thing that works is sending oob Data but as u should not use that anymore...

After the Test written below, u will c that the client connection will get
closed after the expected short time.
**But the server will think its connected, forever...waited 3h so far...**

I tested this so far on a 3.13(Kubuntu) and 3.18(OpenWrt) Linux Kernel.
Is that a bug? I have read many tcp/socket programming books so far...
did not help at all.
Pls pls guys i need ur help :)

I am using asynchronous/Non-blocking io (epoll),
so send and rcv timeouts wont work too.

**UPDATE2:** Now with cut out source for x64/x86

ADD: i thought i could catch the error with epoll event.

but could it be the case that i need to ask the socket if an error occured?

## What i tried so far:

```
#define MAX_EVENTS      64
#define CON_RETRY_TIMEOUT   10      /* time to wait in sec until next connect attempt */
#define CON_TIMEOUT     10      /* time in sec after which stop trying to connect */
#define CON_IDLE        10      /* time in sec after which con.  seems to be dead*/
#define CON_INIT_TIMEOUT    1       /* time till connection gets reinitialized after shutdown */
#define FD_INVAL        -1
#define MAXBUF          4096
#define DEFAULT_IP      "127.0.0.1"
#define DEFAULT_PORT        2000
/* #define NDEBUG */
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#define ERROR(exitcode_when_not_zero, message, ...) \
    error_at_line(exitcode_when_not_zero, errno, __FILE__, __LINE__, \
        message, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define ERROR_GOTO(ziel, exit_status, message, ...) \
    do { \
        ret = exit_status; \
        if (asprintf(&error_msg, message " %s:%s:%u: error: %s", \
            ##__VA_ARGS__, program_invocation_name, \
                __FILE__, __LINE__, strerror(errno)) == -1) \
            ERROR(EXIT_FAILURE, "asprintf ERROR_GOTO"); \
        goto ziel; \
    } while (0)

#define SHUT_SOCKET(fd)                 \
    do {                        \
        if (fd >= 0) {              \
            shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR);    \
            close(fd);          \
            fd = -1;            \
        }                   \
    } while (0)

#define FREE(x) \
    do { \
        if (x != NULL) { \
            free(x); \
            x = NULL; \
        } \
    } while (0)

#define con_err(e) (e == ECONNRESET  || e == EPIPE || e == ETIMEDOUT \
            || e == ECONNABORTED || e == ECONNREFUSED \
            || e == ENETUNREACH || e == EHOSTUNREACH \
            || e == ETIMEDOUT || e == EACCES || e == EPERM)

#define epoll_hup(events) (events & EPOLLERR \
            || events & EPOLLHUP || events & EPOLLRDHUP)

#include <locale.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>
#include <sys/signalfd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <assert.h>

#ifndef strlcpy
#define strlcpy(dst,src,sz) snprintf((dst), (sz), "%s", (src))
#endif

volatile sig_atomic_t sigINT_flag = 0;
volatile sig_atomic_t sigTERM_flag = 0;
const char* program_name    = NULL;
static int tcp_out_sock     = FD_INVAL;
static int tcp_listen_sock  = FD_INVAL;
static int tcp_in_sock      = FD_INVAL;
static int con_timeout_tfd  = FD_INVAL;
static int start_listen_tfd = FD_INVAL;
static unsigned short tcp_in_port = 0;
static unsigned short output_device_port = DEFAULT_PORT;
static char output_device_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = DEFAULT_IP;
int epollfd;

void sigfuncALL(int);
static inline void help(void);
static inline int is_sock_err(int);
static inline int handle_events(int, struct epoll_event *);
static inline int set_sock_opt(int);
static inline int try_connect(char *ip, unsigned short port);
static inline int msg_sock_open(FILE *stream, int sock, int epoll_fd);
static inline int msg_sock_close(FILE *stream, int sock, int epoll_fd);
static inline int start_listen(unsigned short port);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int next_option;

    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    if (sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask) != 0)
        perror("sigemptyset");

    const char* short_options = "s:p:o:h";
    const struct option long_options[] = {
        { "server", 1, NULL, 's' },
        { "out-port", 1, NULL, 'p' },
        { "out-ip", 1, NULL, 'o' },
        { "help", 0, NULL, 'h' },
        { NULL, 0, NULL, 0 }
    };

    program_name = basename(argv[0]);

    do {
        next_option = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_options, long_options, NULL);
        switch (next_option) {
        case 'h':
            help();
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        case 's':
            tcp_in_port = (unsigned short) atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'p':
            output_device_port = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'o':
            strlcpy(output_device_ip, optarg, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            break;
        case '?':
            printf("%s: invalid option: %c\nTry %s --help for more information.\n",
                program_name, next_option, program_name);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        case -1:
            break;
        default:
            abort();
        }
    } while (next_option != -1);

    int ret = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* für ERROR_GOTO */
    char *error_msg = NULL; /* für ERROR_GOTO */
    int retval, nfds;
    struct epoll_event ev, events[MAX_EVENTS];

    epollfd = epoll_create1(0);
    if (epollfd == -1)
        ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE, "");

    act.sa_handler = sigfuncALL;
    if (sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL) != 0)
        ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE, "sigaction SIGTERM");

    act.sa_handler = sigfuncALL;
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) != 0)
        ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE, "sigaction SIGINT");

    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    if (sigaction(SIGPIPE, &act, NULL) != 0)
        ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE, "sigaction SIGPIPE");

    if (tcp_in_port != 0) {
        static struct itimerspec its_listen = {
            .it_value.tv_sec = 1,
        };

        start_listen_tfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);
        if (start_listen_tfd == -1)
            ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE,
                "timerfd_create(start_listen_tfd)");

        if (timerfd_settime(start_listen_tfd, 0, &its_listen, NULL) == -1)
            ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE, "");

        ev.events = EPOLLIN;
        ev.data.fd = start_listen_tfd;
        if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, start_listen_tfd, &ev) == -1)
            ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE, "");
    } else {
        static struct itimerspec its_timeout = {
            .it_value.tv_sec = CON_INIT_TIMEOUT,
            .it_interval.tv_sec = CON_TIMEOUT
        };

        con_timeout_tfd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0);
        if (con_timeout_tfd == -1)
            ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE,
                "timerfd_create(con_timeout_tfd)");

        if (timerfd_settime(con_timeout_tfd, 0, &its_timeout, NULL) == -1)
            ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE, "timerfd_settime(con_retry_tfd)");

        ev.events = EPOLLIN;
        ev.data.fd = con_timeout_tfd;
        if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, con_timeout_tfd, &ev) == -1)
            ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE, "");
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "ip:%s port: %hu\n",
        output_device_ip, output_device_port);

/* mainloop: */
    while (!sigTERM_flag && !sigINT_flag) {
        nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, MAX_EVENTS, -1);
        if (nfds == -1 && errno == EINTR)
            continue;
        else if (nfds == -1)
            ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE, "");

        for (int n = 0; n < nfds; n++) {
            retval = handle_events(epollfd, &events[n]);
            if (retval == -1 && errno == EINTR)
                break;
            else if (retval == -1)
                ERROR_GOTO(done, EXIT_FAILURE, "");
        }
    } /* end mainloop */

done:
    puts("Closing Application properly...\n");

    close(con_timeout_tfd);
    close(start_listen_tfd);

    if (ret != EXIT_SUCCESS)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error_msg);

    FREE(error_msg);

    puts("Terminate " PROG_NAME "\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} /* End main() */

static inline void help(void)
{
    printf(
        "Usage: %s [OPTION]\n"
        "Does something.\n\n"
        "Options:\n"
        "  -s\t--server   \tstart as server\n"
        "  -p\t--out-port\t port to connect to\n"
        "  -o\t--out-ip  \t ip to connect to\n"
        "  -h\t--help    \tDisplay this help\n"
        , program_name
    );

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void sigfuncALL(int sig) {
    switch (sig) {
        case SIGINT:
            sigINT_flag = 1;
            break;
        case SIGTERM:
            sigTERM_flag = 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

static inline int try_connect(char *ip, unsigned short port)
{
    int ret, retval, socket_fd;
    int yes = true;
    int value;
    struct sockaddr_in tcp_addr;

    socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (socket_fd == -1)
        return -1;

    if (set_sock_opt(socket_fd) == -1)
        return -1;

    bzero(&tcp_addr, sizeof(tcp_addr));
    tcp_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    tcp_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
    tcp_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    retval = connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &tcp_addr,
                sizeof(tcp_addr));
    if (retval == -1 && errno == EINPROGRESS)
        ;
    else if (retval == -1) {
        close(socket_fd);
        return -1;
    }

    return socket_fd;
}

static inline int
handle_events(int epoll_fd, struct epoll_event *event)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int retval;
    struct epoll_event ev;
    int bytes_send, bytes_received;
    char buffer[MAXBUF] = {};

    if (epoll_hup(event->events)) {
        fputs("BROKEN\n", stderr);
        msg_sock_close(stderr, event->data.fd, epoll_fd);
    } else if (event->data.fd == tcp_out_sock && event->events & EPOLLOUT) {
        /* tcp output connection established */
        ret = is_sock_err(tcp_out_sock);
        if (ret)
            msg_sock_close(stderr, tcp_out_sock, epoll_fd);
        else
            msg_sock_open(stderr, tcp_out_sock, epoll_fd);
    } else if (event->data.fd == tcp_out_sock && event->events & EPOLLIN) {
        retval = recv(tcp_out_sock, buffer, MAXBUF, MSG_DONTWAIT);
        if (retval > 0) {
            /* TODO */
        } else if (retval == -1 && !(errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
            ERROR(0, " ");
            ret = -1;
            goto done;
        } else if (retval <= 0)
            msg_sock_close(stderr, tcp_out_sock, epoll_fd);
    } else if (event->data.fd == tcp_listen_sock && event->events & EPOLLIN) {
        tcp_in_sock = accept4(tcp_listen_sock, NULL, NULL, SOCK_NONBLOCK);
        if (tcp_in_sock == -1) {
            ret = -1;
            goto done;
        }

        retval = set_sock_opt(tcp_in_sock);
        if (retval == -1) {
            ret = -1;
            goto done;
        }

        /* stop listen */
        msg_sock_close(stderr, tcp_listen_sock, epoll_fd);
        msg_sock_open(stderr, tcp_in_sock, epoll_fd);
    } else if (event->data.fd == tcp_in_sock && event->events & EPOLLIN) {
        while (0 < (bytes_received = recv(tcp_in_sock, buffer, MAXBUF, MSG_DONTWAIT))) {
            /* TODO */
        }

        if (bytes_received == -1 && (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK)) {
        } else if (bytes_received == 0 || (bytes_received == -1 && con_err(errno))) {
            msg_sock_close(stderr, tcp_in_sock, epoll_fd);
        } else if (bytes_received == -1) {
            ret = -1;
            goto done;
        }
    } else if (event->data.fd == con_timeout_tfd && event->events & EPOLLIN) {
        uint64_t numExp;
        if (read(con_timeout_tfd, &numExp, sizeof(uint64_t)) == -1) {
            ret = -1;
            goto done;
        }

        msg_sock_close(stderr, tcp_out_sock, epoll_fd);

        errno = 0;
        tcp_out_sock = try_connect(output_device_ip, output_device_port);
        if (tcp_out_sock == -1 && (con_err(errno))) {
            msg_sock_close(stderr, tcp_out_sock, epoll_fd);
            goto done;
        } else if (tcp_out_sock == -1) {
            ret = -1;
            goto done;
        }

        ev.events = EPOLLOUT;
        ev.data.fd = tcp_out_sock;
        retval = epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, tcp_out_sock, &ev);
        if (retval == -1) {
            ret = -1;
            goto done;
        }
    } else if (event->data.fd == start_listen_tfd && (event->events & EPOLLIN)) {
        uint64_t numExp;
        retval = read(start_listen_tfd, &numExp, sizeof(uint64_t));
        if (retval == -1) {
            ret = -1;
            goto done;
        }

        fprintf(stdout, "start to listen on port: %hu\n", tcp_in_port);

        retval = start_listen(tcp_in_port);
        if (retval == -1 && errno != EADDRINUSE) {
            ret = -1;
            goto done;
        } else if (retval == -1)
            msg_sock_close(stderr, tcp_listen_sock, epoll_fd);

        ev.events = EPOLLIN;
        ev.data.fd = tcp_listen_sock;
        retval = epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, tcp_listen_sock, &ev);
        if (retval == -1) {
            ret = -1;
            goto done;
        }
    }

done:
    return ret;
}

static inline int set_sock_opt(int socket_fd)
{
    int value;
    int yes = true;
    int ret = 0;
    int retval;

    /* IPPROTO_TCP causes endpoint not connected error on 3.13 ubuntu  */
    retval = setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR,
                &yes, sizeof(yes));
    if (retval == -1) {
        ret = -1;
        goto done;
    }

    yes = true;
    retval = setsockopt(socket_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, SO_KEEPALIVE,
                &yes, sizeof(yes));
    if (retval == -1) {
        ret = -1;
        goto done;
    }

    yes = true;
    retval = setsockopt(socket_fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_RECVERR,
                &yes, sizeof(yes));
    if (retval == -1) {
        ret = -1;
        goto done;
    }

    /* keepalive probes */
    value = 2;
    retval = setsockopt(socket_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT,
                &value, sizeof(value));
    if (retval == -1) {
        ret = -1;
        goto done;
    }

    /* seconds of idle before sending keepalive probes */
    value = 10;
    retval = setsockopt(socket_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE,
                &value, sizeof(value));
    if (retval == -1) {
        ret = -1;
        goto done;
    }

    /* seconds between keepalive probes */
    value = 1;
    retval = setsockopt(socket_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL,
                &value, sizeof(value));
    if (retval == -1) {
        ret = -1;
        goto done;
    }

done:
    return ret;
}

static inline int is_sock_err(int socket)
{
    socklen_t optlen = sizeof(int);
    int optval;

    if (getsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void*) &optval, &optlen))
        return -1;

    if (optval)
        return optval;

    return 0;
}

static inline int
msg_sock_close(FILE *stream, int sock, int epoll_fd)
{
    if (!stream /*|| sock < 0*/) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in peer_addr = {};
    socklen_t peer_addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    int ret = 0;
    struct epoll_event ev;
    socklen_t optlen = sizeof(int);
    int optval;

    if (!(sock < 0) || errno == 0) {
        ret = getpeername(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr,
            &peer_addr_len);
        if (ret == -1 && !(errno == ENOTSOCK || errno == ENOTCONN))
            return -1;

        ret = getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void*) &optval, &optlen);
        if (ret == -1 && errno != ENOTSOCK)
            return -1;
    }

    if (sock == tcp_out_sock) {
        fprintf(stream, "tcp output to: %s:%hu closed. Reason: %s\n",
            inet_ntoa(peer_addr.sin_addr), peer_addr.sin_port,
                errno == 0 ? strerror(optval) : strerror(errno));

        /* arm */
        struct itimerspec its_timeout = {
            .it_value.tv_sec = CON_INIT_TIMEOUT,
            .it_interval.tv_sec = CON_TIMEOUT
        };

        if (timerfd_settime(con_timeout_tfd, 0, &its_timeout, NULL) == -1)
            return -1;

        SHUT_SOCKET(tcp_out_sock);

        if (tcp_in_sock != FD_INVAL
            && epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL,
                    tcp_in_sock, &ev) == -1)
                        return -1;
    } else if (sock == tcp_in_sock) {
        fprintf(stream, "tcp input from: %s:%hu closed. Reason: %s\n",
            inet_ntoa(peer_addr.sin_addr), peer_addr.sin_port, strerror(optval));
        SHUT_SOCKET(tcp_in_sock);

        /* arm */
        struct itimerspec its_retry = {
            .it_value.tv_sec = CON_INIT_TIMEOUT};

        if (timerfd_settime(start_listen_tfd, 0, &its_retry, NULL) == -1)
            return -1;
    } else if (sock == tcp_listen_sock) {
        SHUT_SOCKET(tcp_listen_sock);
        fprintf(stream, "tcp listen closed\n");

        if (tcp_in_sock == FD_INVAL) {
            /* arm */
            struct itimerspec its_retry = {
                .it_value.tv_sec = CON_INIT_TIMEOUT};

            if (timerfd_settime(start_listen_tfd, 0, &its_retry, NULL) == -1)
                return -1;
        }
    } else {
        close(sock);
        sock = FD_INVAL;
    }

    return 0;
}

static inline int
msg_sock_open(FILE *stream, int sock, int epoll_fd)
{
    if (!stream || sock < 0) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in peer_addr = {};
    socklen_t peer_addr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    int ret = 0;
    struct epoll_event ev;
    int retval;

    ret = getpeername(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr,
                &peer_addr_len);
    if (ret == -1 && errno == ENOTSOCK)
        return -1;

    if (sock == tcp_out_sock) {
        fprintf(stream, "tcp output to: %s:%hu opened\n",
            inet_ntoa(peer_addr.sin_addr), peer_addr.sin_port);

        /* disarm */
        struct itimerspec its_timeout = {
            .it_value.tv_sec = 0,
            .it_value.tv_nsec = 0
        };

        if (timerfd_settime(con_timeout_tfd, 0, &its_timeout, NULL) == -1)
            return -1;

        ev.events = EPOLLIN;
        ev.data.fd = tcp_out_sock;
        if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, tcp_out_sock, &ev) == -1)
            return -1;

        if (tcp_in_sock != FD_INVAL) {
            ev.events = EPOLLIN;
            ev.data.fd = tcp_in_sock;
            retval = epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD,
                        tcp_in_sock, &ev);
            if (retval == -1)
                return -1;
        }
    } else if (sock == tcp_in_sock) {
        fprintf(stream, "tcp input from: %s:%hu opened\n",
            inet_ntoa(peer_addr.sin_addr), peer_addr.sin_port);

        ev.events = EPOLLIN;
        ev.data.fd = tcp_in_sock;
        if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, tcp_in_sock, &ev) == -1)
            return -1;
    } else if (sock == tcp_listen_sock) {
        ev.events = EPOLLIN;
        ev.data.fd = tcp_listen_sock;
        if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, tcp_listen_sock, &ev) == -1)
            return -1;

        /* disarm */
        struct itimerspec its_listen = {
            .it_value.tv_sec = 0,
            .it_interval.tv_sec = 0
        };

        if (timerfd_settime(start_listen_tfd, 0, &its_listen, NULL) == -1) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static inline int
start_listen(unsigned short port)
{
    assert(tcp_listen_sock == FD_INVAL);

    int flag = 1;
    struct sockaddr_in sock_addr;
    int retval, ret = 0;

    tcp_listen_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (tcp_listen_sock == -1)
        return -1;

    sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sock_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    retval = set_sock_opt(tcp_listen_sock);
    if (retval == -1) {
        ret = -1;
        goto done;
    }

    retval = bind(tcp_listen_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sock_addr,
            sizeof(sock_addr));
    if (retval == -1) {
        ret = -1;
        goto done;
    }

    retval = listen(tcp_listen_sock, 5);
    if (retval == -1) {
        ret = -1;
        goto done;
    }

done:
    if (ret == -1)
        SHUT_SOCKET(tcp_listen_sock);

    return ret;
}
```

## What i read so far:

[Getting disconnection notification using TCP Keep-Alive on write blocked socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320039/getting-disconnection-notification-using-tcp-keep-alive-on-write-blocked-socket)

[How to set socket timeout in C when making multiple connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181784/how-to-set-socket-timeout-in-c-when-making-multiple-connections/12948084#12948084)

[Application control of TCP retransmission on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907527/application-control-of-tcp-retransmission-on-linux)

[TCP, recv function hanging despite KEEPALIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076858/tcp-recv-function-hanging-despite-keepalive)

[How can I detect TCP dead-connection in linux on C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592608/how-can-i-detect-tcp-dead-connection-in-linux-on-c)

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html

[Do I need to heartbeat to keep a TCP connection open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865987/do-i-need-to-heartbeat-to-keep-a-tcp-connection-open)

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

Almost every Linux/Unix Related network programming book from 2010 onwards.
And of course William Richard Stevens books :)

Maybe i have overseen something?

## How to test:

### Server:

```
socat -dd tcp-listen:2000,keepalive,keepidle=10,keepcnt=2,reuseaddr,keepintvl=1 -
```

### Client:

```
socat -dd - tcp:localhost:2000,keepalive,keepidle=10,keepcnt=2,keepintvl=1
```

### Drop Connection (Unplug Cable, Shut down Link(WiFi/Interface))

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2000 -j DROP
```

### Watch result:

```
watch -n 1 'netstat -otn | grep :2000'
```

### Socat Version:

socat version 1.7.2.3 on Feb  1 2014 17:08:10

## Test with C source:

### Server:

```
keepbug -s 2000
```

### Client:

```
keepbug -o 127.0.0.1 -p 2000
```

### Note:

If u start the client without options it will default to 127.0.0.1:2000

The Iptables rules seems to drop none of the connection now, maybe need a second device where the server runs on to shut of to simulate the dead link.

Comment: Have you Googled at all for 'TCP half-open connections"? That should give you a plethora of information.

Comment: Yes i did, all links on the first site :) was even reading the .net information blog. The list with the 4 things u can do in there did not help, cause i cant/wont implement an osi layer 7 proto and and the keep alive is not working and the timeout thing can lead to data loss on high traffic.

Comment: How much traffic is going between the client and server? If you're sending information continually (or fairly often) then the 10 second idle time won't get reached and no keepalive probes will be sent.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why would 'the the timeout thing can lead to data loss on high traffic'?

Comment: @MichaelAlbers - yeah, if data is already flowing freely, no need for the peer poll...

Comment: @MichaelAlbers 23-92 byte data every avg. 250us. The problem is to detect a broken link (machine gets shut down) then there is no data at all.  @ Martin JamesData loss would occur cause the kernel socket buffer gets an overrun in the time from shutdown to reestablish, if a burst right at that time would come in.

Comment: @BookerB If your data is being sent that often you will probably need to roll your own keepalive since TCP isn't going to hit the 10 second idle time. Try researching TCP heartbeats.

Comment: @Michael Albers ? if the link is down it should hit the timeout, cause of no input anymore? TCP Heartbeat is a layer 7 implementation, cause of zero copy thats not a cool solution :) or u mean inside of tcp implementation, i.e. the network Stack? Should'nt the KEEPALIVE timer kick in as soon as there is no data flow anymore?

Comment: @BookerB Since you do not want to implement layer 7 heartbeats, which in combination with your own timers, is the proper way of doing this (and if you just send/receive stuff once a second, you're not losing out on performance or the zero-copy you seem to worry about), the only other option is to use TCP Keepalive, which you do. However you have not shown the actual code where you attempt to detect a broken TCP connection. So perhaps you just have a bug in that code, which is much more likely than a bug in the kernel.

Comment: @nos u dont actually need to code a line to test this :) i posted a comandline test that u can do with socat. I just registered the socket for epoll. Epoll should catch the hup right?
    #define epoll_hup(events) (events & EPOLLERR \
   || events & EPOLLHUP || events & EPOLLRDHUP)

Comment: @BookerB I have my own server code that detects this using TCP keepalive and it works perfectly fine. I don't know how socat works, what to expect from socat with these options you show, so I am not going to debug that.

Comment: @BookerB your iptables rule there though is wrong, the -D should be -A

Comment: @nos yeah thx fixed, that was the command to get the rule out again :), i dont have the code here but i think it was waiting for epoll_wait to report the specific event

Comment: @BookerB Ok, that's likely the wrong way to do it though. However if I run your 2 socat commands and a proper IP tables rule, the socat commands exits after about 10 seconds, so that seems to work fine. I'm still pretty confident there's a bug on the code you arn't showing us.

Comment: @nos Whats is the right way? if u enter the server command first, client command second, ENTER NOTHING on both sides and enter the ip tables rule i posted above, Just the client exits for me, so either socat version: socat version 1.7.2.3 on Feb  1 2014 17:08:10 or the stack is broken or i am doing something wrong, but what? I will post more code Monday, but its just an epoll_wait and check the HUP events if epoll_wait returns.

Comment: @BookerB Well, that's why I said I don't want to debug socat. Perhaps it sits and waits for a new connection. Perhaps it has a bug. You could run it with the `strace` tool and see what it does.  Normally you just read()/recv() from the socket and handle errors from those functions, it's that simple. If you use poill/select/epoll, that requires you to wait for read events all the time. If you use epoll in edge trigger mode, stuf is easy to mess up though. Now, just give people some code to debug, I'm sure someone will find the bug.

Comment: @nos yeah think so, thx 4 the help. i need to unroll all functions and remove unimportant stuff, needs time haha, i dont use edge triggerd mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG what a noob error :) i found it

## Diff:

```
17c17
<   retval = setsockopt(socket_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, SO_KEEPALIVE,
---
>   retval = setsockopt(socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE,
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a reasonable read timeout, via SO_RCVTIMEO, with blocking mode. Set it like my enoguh that you won't frivolously disconnect live clients but short enoguh that you don't tie up dead sockets and threads for hours.