# Is there any way to set specific application timeout with SO_KEEPALIVE instead of depending on system default timeout i.e 2hrs in C

Tags: c

I'm using blocking socket with SSL_read on server side.In some un expected conditions if the client die i need to disconnect that specific client connection on server side with SO_KEEPALIVE.How can i setsockopt with 5 minutes SO_KEEPALIVE ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In some OSes, yes. Which one are you looking for an answer for?

Comment: `SO_KEEPALIVE` is probably not the option you were looking for (keep-alive is for keeping idle connection alive), `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` are the one you want to set, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4182564/105104)

Comment: Looking for Centos @Shawn

Comment: is there any other problems do we face if we use SO_RCVTIMEO @dvhh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux, you can adjust the timeout on a socket that's had `SO_KEEPALIVE` turned on with the `TCP_KEEPIDLE` option. It takes a time in seconds:

```
int timeout = 300;
setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, &timeout, sizeof timeout);
```