# Setsockopt function with time limit is not working in C on hp non-stop

Tags: c, tandem

I am trying to set up timeout for receiving data via socket.

```
 struct timeval 
 {
     time_t      tv_sec;
     long int    tv_usec;
 };

struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 5;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd == -1)
{
      sprintf(RESULTS, "%s","ERROR");
      return 0;
}
else
{
        /*Connecting to server socket*/
        if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0)
        {
            /*Writing results back to COBOL variable*/
            sprintf(RESULTS, "%s","!SENT");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
          if(setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,&tv,sizeof(tv)) < 0)
          {
             if(send(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0)<0)
             {
                /*Writing results back to COBOL variable*/
                sprintf(RESULTS, "%s","ERROR");
                /*Closing the socket*/
                FILE_CLOSE_((short)sockfd);
                return 0;
             }
            else
            {
                /* Receiving data from server*/
                bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
                recv(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff),0);
                    
                /*Writing results back to COBOL variable*/
                sprintf(RESULTS, "%s","SUCCESS");

                /*Closing the socket*/
                FILE_CLOSE_((short)sockfd);
                return 0;
            }
          }
        }
     
}
```

> Expected output: Program should wait for 5 secs and if it doesn't get reply from the server then it should close the socket and get out of it.

> Actual Output: Warning:argument 4 conflicts with formal definition

Implemented based on this example, [I found an example in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181784/how-to-set-socket-timeout-in-c-when-making-multiple-connections)

But this is not working on Tandem-C

I have referred to the C/C++ programming manual for Tandem but didn't found with timeout. [Tandem-Manual](http://nonstoptools.com/manuals/TcpIP-Programming.pdf)-Page 185

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "not working".  Please show the code you've tried, along with any input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: The silly library uses `char *optval` as the 4th argument. Newer (Posix) versions (such as Linux) use a `void *optval` , which can be passed without a cast.

Comment: Thank you! @wildplasser
That solves my Warning,
Currently, No warning but 
setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_RCVTIMEO,&timeout,sizeof(timeout))  is giving -1

So, It's not setting the timeout.

Comment: You should check `errno` on a `-1` return. (maybe this IOCTL is not implemented)

Comment: Sorry @wildplasser , I misread my program!
Error no is : 330

Comment: I don't see SO_RCVTIMEO mentioned in hp-nonstop manuals, however its defined in the sys/socket.h, you need to check with hp-nonstop support to confirm if SO_RCVTIMEO is implemented or not

Comment: It is there in tandem libraries,

`#define SO_SNDTIMEO     0x1005  /* send timeout */
#define SO_RCVTIMEO     0x1006  /* receive timeout */`

Comment: Read my earlier comment again. SO_RCVTIMEO is there in the header file that's why your code compiled. But hp-nonstop might not have implemented it as it(SO_RCVTIMEO) is not mentioned in the manual of hp-nonstop programming. I guess only hp-nonstop support could confirm that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a particular problem to tandem.

For some historical reason sockelen_t is defined as a palin int.
But sizeof returns an unissigned int.
You need to define a socklen variable and set is to the sizeof value.

Something like:

```
socklen_t sl;
sl = (int) sizeof(timeout);
```

Comment: `int timeout=5;
 int error;
socklen_t sl;
sl = (int) sizeof(timeout);
error=setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(char*)&timeout,sl);`

I have tried like this and there is no timeout and error no is 330!!!

Comment: timeout should be a timeval struct not a plain int!

Comment: I added as struct but still no result!!

Answer (score -1):

```cpp
        qcap = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
        int timeout = 1798;
        setsockopt(qcap, 6, 18, (char*)&timeout, sizeof(timeout));
        connect(qcap, (sockaddr *)&server_bn, sizeof(server_bn));
```

https://github.com/alexeyneu/BlockZero/blob/29ed505a211d14d4577012438cd8bec9d15f1272/connection/x.cpp#L93-L96

Comment: Nope! It's not working!
Same error no and it doesn't give expected output!

Comment: it works. it's about your hardware os or whatever else you run

Comment: may be cobol is a weak link